# Formatting Postgresql dates with Timezone

Tags: postgresql

How can I output postgresql dates with [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)-compliant timezones?

e.g. I have the value

```
2006-11-10 07:35:30+01
```

and I need it in this format:

```
2006-11-10T07:35+01
```

I could do that easily enough with string manipulation, but the standard date formatting functions for

```
to_char(<my date>, 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mmTD')
```

would give me this:

```
2006-11-10T07:11CET
```

instead of this:

```
2006-11-10T07:11+02
```

Is there a way to get the timzone as an offset instead of as an abbreviation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using string manipulation, maybe? Like:

```
regexp_replace(current_date || 'T' || current_time, E':[^:]*?\\+', E'+');
```

or

```
replace( regexp_replace(now()::text, E':[^:]*?\\+', E'+'), ' ', 'T' );
```

Not elegant, but it gets the job done (tested with 8.3)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late, but here is an alternative:

```
to_char(now(), 'YYYY-MM-DDThh:mi')::timestamp with time zone::text
```

**Nota:** I have replaced `mm` to `mi` in the above expression since I think that minutes are expected instead of months after the hour.